# Is it disallowed or only discouraged to use Resource Owner flow and what is the alternative?

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0, authorization

We have the controversy of picking a proper security flow and the suggestion of Resource Owner Password flow was presented. In [IEFT draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-14#section-2.4) it's said that one must not use it, while [Auth0's docs](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/resource-owner-password-flow) states that it's not recommended in general but feasible if the encouraged flows aren't available.

> The resource owner password credentials grant MUST NOT be used. This grant type insecurely exposes the credentials of the resource owner to the client.

> Though we do not recommend it, highly-trusted applications can use the Resource Owner Password Flow ..., which requests that users provide credentials ...

While it's obvious there's no much love for the ROP flow, there's still quite some middle ground between *absolutely must not* and *should under a condition*. And if Auth Code Exchange flow isn't possible (as in our scenario), there's still the need to pick something.

In our case, the team decided to skip ROP flow and use Client Credentials flow motivating it as a more secure alternative. I don't get how it is so, since the client now will expose all the goodies based on its ID and secret, while in ROP flow, one needs to also send username and password.

1. Is Resource Owner Password flow absolutely not to be used?
2. Is Client Credentials flow actually more secure and if so how?

Comment: Well, who would disallow you? :) It's all about risk. Make sure you understand the risk of Resource Owner Password flow, what components are trusted, what if they are compromised, what kind of attacker will gain what and so on. Most importantly in this case, how will the resource owner's password go through your apps, what components would have access to the password, how could those be compromised and so on. If you are ok with the risk and deliberately accept it, sure, you can use that flow too. But there _is_ a significant risk involved in most cases, that's why it's warned against.

Comment: @GaborLengyel While I agree with your comment, I can't really see how it relates to the actual question being asked. Perhaps I need to make it more clear. It's said in the draft *must not be used*. That doesn't align with your point *learn the risks, apply with precaution*. Also, there's the question of what to use instead and why CC flow would be more secure, despite the remark I made in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) flow is deprecated - basically from the start - because it defeats one of the primary purposes of OAuth 2, which is to not disclose the end user credentials to the Client. The draft you are referring to is slated to be incorporated in to OAuth 2.1, a revision of the spec that will make it a MUST NOT based on the experience of over a decade of OAuth 2.0 deployment.

The rationale: if you really want to embed direct username/password authentication in an application, there's no reason to use OAuth 2.x. Just use basic authorization, LDAP or some other existing way of presenting a username/password from an application to a backend. The OAuth working group recognises in hindsight that incorporating ROPC in to OAuth 2 was a mistake because it defeats the purpose of OAuth , creates confusion and doesn't offer any benefit over existing alternatives, hence the MUST NOT in the revision.

The Client Credentials (CC) flow addresses a inherently different use case of OAuth 2.0 that does not deal with Resource Owners or end users. If somehow the CC flow is used to implement the ROPC use case, that's a serious abuse of the protocol and its intention leading to the same problems as with ROPC.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I have a FUQ to that. What I was aiming for was to use CC flow but let each connecting party to identify themselves using name/pass that **we'd provide**. So no exposure of anything we don't already know, since we'd give them the pass along with the client's secret. That way, I was planning to discriminate different authorizations level included in the token but using a single client instance. As it's now, **anybody** with the right secret and ID of the client is allowed to do **precisely** the same stuff. We'll need a bunch of individual clients.